# How do you convert JSON Blob into Columns and Values

Tags: mysql, json

I have a `VP/MS MySQL` table with a "ref" column incorporating a unique identifier and a "request" column essentially incorporating a complete JSON response message in BLOB format. The message looks like this:

```
{
    "vars": {

    },
    "computes": {
        "P_PRERefId_str": {
            "=": "12421321"
        },
        "P_PolicyNumber_str": {
            "=": "1234567890"
        },
        "P_YearlyPolicyFeeAmt_rea": {
            "=": "70.56"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can somehow extract the JSON key-value pairs into 3 columns and corresponding values like:

```
P_PRERefId_str   P_Policy    P_YearlyPolicyFeeAmt_rea
12421321         1234567890  70.56
```

Comment: The following [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rjLh5UBQNWuEaCf9Ecvrgy/0) can give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for. First, turn your JSON into a PHP object.

```
$myObject = json_decode('{
    "vars": {},
    "computes": {
        "P_PRERefId_str": {
            "=": "12421321"
        },
        "P_PolicyNumber_str": {
            "=": "1234567890"
        },
        "P_YearlyPolicyFeeAmt_rea": {
            "=": "70.56"
        }
    }
}');
```

Then, iterate through the "computes" attribute and insert the properties into your DB.

```
foreach ($myObject->computes as $column => $attr) {
    foreach ($attr as $equalSign => $val) {
    // INSERT $val INTO $column
    // Depending on your Driver (PDO, framework ORM)
    // Your code will differ here
}};
```

Comment: Thanks for that Kirill - I should add that on a scale of 1-10 of technical literacy I would be a 2; and that I was looking to use MySQL Workbench to extract the JSON message stored in the blob field of the table into a column header row with multiple columns based on the JSON Keys, and their corresponding Values in the relevant rows underneath.